# How to add an event listener for a SweetAlert promise result?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have this alert function and I want to have an addListener to this so if the user clicks ok it redirects the page. How would you set this for the default ok button in an alert?

```
 function SuccessDelete() {
        swal("Success!", "File successfully deleted.", "success"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `swal()` method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise). When the alert is closed, it resolves with a *result* (`confirmed`). The result will be `true` when the "OK" button is pressed. If closed any other way, it will be `null`:

```js
function SuccessDelete() {
  swal("Success!", "File successfully deleted.", "success").then(function(confirmed) {
    if(confirmed) {
      console.log("Ok button pressed, redirect here...");
    }
  });
}

SuccessDelete();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

See the "*using promises*" section of the [documentation](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using SweetAlert2, but got the syntax wrong (you forgot the `.fire()` portion.

If you pass it a configuration object, then it accepts an `onClose` argument where you can pass a callback function.

```js
function successDelete() {
  swal.fire({
    title: "Success!",
    titleText: "File successfully deleted.",
    html: "success",
    onClose: callback
  });
}

function callback() {
  document.body.style.background = 'black';
}

successDelete();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<div id=html></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The code was directly from their website thou.